# Exactly how do I specify the location of the PDF template in a FDF file?

Tags: php, pdf, download, acrobat, fdf

I've written a PHP server script that downloads a FDF file to the user when he clicks on a button. This FDF was generated with dummy values for form fields with Acrobat Pro from the original interactive PDF template. I replace the dummy arguments in the PHP code and download the result to the user.

My problem is that Acrobat starts up but cannot find the corresponding PDF. I've inserted the complete URL of the template PDF in the /F and/UF fields of the FDF, but it doesn't seem to work. The template URL has the same path as the FDF (except for the actual filename extension). What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Kindly post some of your code so that we can help you.

Comment: I can't fit the FDF in the comments.

Comment: You might be confusing Acrobat by setting both /F and /UF. The /UF is the unicode version of the URL, you generally need only the /F.

Comment: Acrobat itself adds both the /U and /UF to its FDF export. Can you provide a link to the FDF file? Or at the very least provide your /F and /UF values in your question.

Comment: I've set up a sample here: http://www.mxsmanic.com/documents/mytest_data.fdf. Visiting this URL causes the FDF to download, but then Acrobat asks where the corresponding PDF is. And yet if you look in the FDF, the complete path of the PDF file is given. I can't find any decent documentation on FDF, so I'm stuck.

Comment: Not sure if Adobe will honor a URL, typically it is a relative path meant to be on the local file system. Regardless, the PDF spec says that /UF takes precedence over the /F entry, so at the very least the fact that your /UF entry is just the filename might be an issue. Try setting /UF to the same value as /F

Comment: I've set both fields to a URL but still can't get it to work. I don't understand how Adobe intends this to be used. How is Acrobat supposed to find the PDF corresponding to a FDF if it only can handle a simple filename? Logically if you're downloading the FDF from a web site, you need to download the PDF, too.